# Designer Files suddenly require Global prefix

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

---

Edit, this is fixed. Will post answer and mark as answer when my restricted account allows me to do so.

### The new control was referencing a code-behind file from another project, this meant the references from the project where I added the user control were no longer specific to the project. Correcting this resolved this issue.

Something very peculiar happened this morning, and I can't resolve it easily.

Working away in Visual Studio, added a new user control (.ascx file), and suddenly all of my current controls that use a MasterPage suddenly require the `Global.` prefix in their Design.vb files.

Can anyone explain this, is it a visual studio bug?

I have unloaded and reloaded the project to no avail. I have also checked project changes, and the only change is the adding of my new control!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new control was referencing a code-behind file from another project, this meant the references from the project where I added the user control were no longer specific to the project. Correcting this resolved this issue.